# Getting no bootable device on laptop, but the hard disk is working fine on other computer

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios

I got no bootable device on my 2-year-old laptop Acer Aspire 515-51G a couple of days back. It had windows 10 pre-installed in it. I tried to install ubuntu but got the same error although the hard disk was showing up from the "live ubuntu desktop environment" (try ubuntu feature).[image: This is what the drive content looked like]

So today I again disconnected the hdd from the laptop, connected it to another pc, and installed ubuntu in it, installation worked fine and ubuntu was working fine. So the HDD isn't a problem.

Connected back the HDD to the laptop, again the same error- No bootable device.

I feel the problem is in the bios somewhere but I am not sure how to fix it. I have tried changing the boot menu to legacy (initially it was UEFI). Also have tried disabling secure boot mode, but haven't gotten lucky yet.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the Ubuntu Live USB also is not bootable, as well as the HDD? If the USB is bootable and not the HDD, I'd image it and/or save everything from it with another PC, and then delete all partitions and install Ubuntu to make it bootable... and that should work with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: I have tried to format the hard drive and delete all partitions after taking backup of my important files and again tried to install Ubuntu but still got no bootable device. One interesting thing is, I connected this HDD to another pc and installed ubuntu in it, and it worked fine. So i am guessing the HDD is good, and the issue is either with bios or the cable. But since the HDD was showing up with live Ubuntu problem might not be with the cable either.

Comment: Perhaps a BIOS/UEFI change was made that is causing the issue, since the HDD clearly *does* work, is bootable with Ubuntu on another PC... or it could be a controller, a cable or other hardware issue.

Comment: I had a very similar problem on my old pc.UEFI would complain no bootable device found when only ssd was attatched and would prefer to boot from any other bootable USB/hdd when attached completely ignoring the ssd. Beside that ssd behaved normal in every way.But i was eable to boot from ssd by accessing boot menu (by pressing f12) and selecting windows boot manager from the list.Had to do this manually even on reboots. If i recall correctly, the issue automatically vanished after i installed linux beside windows but reappeared after changed some settings in UEFI. ....continued

Comment: And to test i deleted my old linux and reinstalled and again that error was gone again. I even recall that 'no bootable device' error popped only after i changed some settings in the UEFI at first place.So try it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I didn't made any change to bios before this issue started. I had never even opened bios as far as I remember on this device.@Madhubala I can't access boot menu for some reason. I have tried various keys (F8/F12) but the no bootable device error screen comes directly.

Comment: Also to add, I have also tried reseting the bios to default but it hadn't helped either.